# upload image with firestore and vue.js [Cannot read property 'id' of undefined]

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-storage, vuex

I'm using element.io to upload images to firebase with vue.js, it's fine, it works. The problem is when I want to update a field of a model, I get this error.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of
>   undefined

```
methods () {

    upload(file, fileList) {
      this.photo = file.file

      if (this.photo) {

        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profiles/avatar/'+Date.now()+'/'+this.photo.name);
        let uploadTask = storageRef.put(this.photo)

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
          var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');

        }, function(error) {
        }, function() {
          var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
         firebase.database().ref('/profiles/' + this.$store.getters.profile.id ).update({ avatar: downloadURL })
        })

      }

    }

}
```

An error appears in this line, when using the variables that are in my data, I get the same error

```
    function() {
       var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
       firebase.database().ref('/profiles/' + this.$store.getters.profile.id )
       .update({ avatar: downloadURL }) })
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `this.$store.getters.profile` is returning `undefined`. Ensure that `profile` is properly being set and that you're retrieving the value correctly.

Comment: @B.Fleming  the getters are correct, I'm using it in a calculation, but I do not know why that part does not work

Comment: Maybe `this` is different in the `uploadTask` callbacks? Try console logging it and/or setting `let that = this` after the `if` and using `that.$store.getters.profile.id`.